# Why is my AppWidget not using the label provided?

Tags: android, android-widget

I've specified android:label in the XML app widget provider, but the name specified is not being used when you do Home->Widgets->...  Instead the name of the app is used, the default if no label is provided. The dimensions from the configuration are being used correctly.

```
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:label="@string/widget_title"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="21600000"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

And then in my resources:

```
<string name="widget_title">My Widget Name</string>
```

The string resource referenced in the widget XML config is validated by the IDE, so why is the string resource not being used?

Comment: I removed the dependency on the string resource, and specifying android:label="My Widget Name" it still fails to use the name provided.

Comment: It works fine if I set the label in the widget <receiver> tag in AndroidManifest.xml, e.g. android:label="@string/widget_title"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify `android:label="@string/widget_title"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `receiver` section for your widget.

Not in `appwidget-provider` in your `widget_info.xml`.

Comment: How do you get the name of the widget to show up below the widget on the home screen like it does for apps?

Comment: in my case its not working i add android:label="@string/widget_title" in provider receiver in manifest.xml